# how to unique data group validation in form request laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, request, laravel-9, laravel-request

I have two column 'book_name' & 'writer' in 'books' table. When new data insert i want to check the same book and writer not will be added. But i dont understand how to do this. here is my code.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'book_name' => 'required|unique:books,book_name,' . $this->id,
        'writer' => 'required|unique:books,writer,' . $this->id,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique), unique rule is applied by defining the rule, stating the table and column name e.g.

```
unique:table,column
```

alternativelly if you're using eloquent models it can be

```
unique:path\to\model,column
```

The `. $this->id` constructor should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'book_name' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('books')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where('writer', request('writer')))
                ->ignore($this->id)
        ],

        'writer' => 'required',
    ];
}
```